# I have problem Page not found (404) Django

Tags: python, django, url

```
import jobs.views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('nick', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),
]


    enter code here

    
    def nick(request):
           return render(request, 'jobs/nick.html')
```

I got:
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/nick/

Using the URLconf defined in FadhelPro.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
nick/ [name='nick']
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: Have you tried without trailing slash? http://127.0.0.1:8000/nick

Comment: If your using the new version of django, when you write "127.0.0.1:8000/nick" it becomes "127.0.0.1:8000/nick/" So the url path needs to be `path('nick/', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```py
path('nick', jobs.views.nick, name='nick')
```

Try:

```py
path(r'^nick/', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),
```

Comment: I did it but still doesn't work. when I  cancel this line of code the website work. the problem in this line of code: path(r'^nick/', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),

Answer (score 0):

If python -V is 3.x or above then:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('nick/', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),
]


def nick(request):
       return render(request, 'jobs/nick.html')
```

If python -V is 2.x or above then:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^nick/', jobs.views.nick, name='nick'),
]


def nick(request):
       return render(request, 'jobs/nick.html')
```

Html templates could not be rendered without an app but you can write the code of the html in a http response!

If you create an app instead that will be more hacky and good.If this doesn't work then you go for an app and Get some tutorials of django before you mess up!!